# Show or hide a div using Javascript and/or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has 9 html tags (text input, select, button types) and these 9 controls are inside a div.
This div is `"display: none"`  ie. the 9 controls inside the div are not visible when the page appears in the browser.

If the user clicks a button I have a Javascript function handling its 'onclick':

```
   function handleShowTheDiv()
   {
       var theDiv = document.getElementById('theNineControlDiv');
       theDiv.style = "display: visible";
   }
```

Although I realize I could have this button submit the page and then in my php, I could output the extra 9 controls, for reasons I won't go into I don't want to submit the page just to make the extra 9 controls visible.

The above isn't working.

I don't remember the details but I read something somewhere that used javascript and css somehow to show/hide things on the page.  How do you do that?   I thought that changing the `style` of the div from `"display: none"` to `"display: visible"` would do it but it is not working.

Comment: Try "display: block" instead of "display: visible" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
function handleShowTheDiv()
   {
       var theDiv = document.getElementById('theNineControlDiv');
       theDiv.style.display = "block";
   }
```

you can change just about any css this way, so read more about [the style object on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style)

Comment: you're missing the quotes on the value: theDiv.style.display = "visible";

Comment: @codewombat duh, thanks. not to mention my blindness to correct display values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function showDiv()
{
 // This is to show the div
  document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'block';
}

 function hideDiv()
{
 // This is to hide the div
  document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'none';
}
```

The code won't support, if the div has the **runat** property..

Hope this will help you..